# Generics and EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I’m working on project in Swift (XCode 6.3.1). During runtime I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` (I’m testing on simulator iPhone 6, but when I use unit test class, I get this error also):

This shows of structure my code:

```
// File IPerson.swift    
public protocol IPerson {
    var firstName : String? { get set }
    var secondName : String? { get set }    
}
```

```
// File PersonHelper.swift    
public class PersonHelper<T:IPerson> {
    public init(){
    }

    public func doSomething(person : T) -> Int {
        var secondName = person.secondName;
        //...
        return 0;
    }    
}
```

```
// File SamplePerson.swift    
public class SamplePerson: IPerson {
    public init() {
    }

    public var firstName : String?;
    public var secondName : String?;
}
```

```
// In some viewController (or in test class)
…
 var helper = PersonHelper<SamplePerson>();
 var person = SamplePerson();
 var result = helper.doSomething(person)
…
```

When I use this version of `IPerson` protocol (changed order of properties!) evrything is ok.

```
// File IPerson.swift    
public protocol IPerson {
    var secondName : String? { get set }
    var firstName : String? { get set }    
}
```

This behaviour is very strange for me - the order of properties in protocol is important? 
When I use non-generic `PersonHelper` everything is ok too, but I need generic class. 
When I put all protocols and class in one file (place from I execute `doSomething` method - viewController or testclass) also everything is ok.

It’s somthing wrong in my code, or this is bug in Swift language?

Stack trace:

```
#0  0x00007f8d4840e350 in 0x7f8d4840e350 ()
#1  0x000000010449e253 in protocol witness for SampleProject.IPerson.firstName.materializeForSet : Swift.Optional<Swift.String> in conformance SampleProject.SamplePerson : SampleProject.IPerson in SampleProject at /Users/bjarko/Documents/XCode Projects/SampleProject/SampleProject/SamplePerson.swift:20
#2  0x000000010449e53e in SampleProject.PersonHelper.doSomething <A : SampleProject.IPerson>(SampleProject.PersonHelper<A>)(A) -> Swift.Int at /Users/bjarko/Documents/XCode Projects/SampleProject/SampleProject/Helper.swift:16
#3  0x0000000104499d35 in SampleProject.ViewController.viewDidLoad (SampleProject.ViewController)() -> () at /Users/bjarko/Documents/XCode Projects/SampleProject/SampleProject/ViewController.swift:18
#4  0x0000000104499dc2 in @objc SampleProject.ViewController.viewDidLoad (SampleProject.ViewController)() -> () ()
#5  0x0000000105058210 in -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] ()
#6  0x000000010505840e in -[UIViewController view] ()
#7  0x0000000104f732c9 in -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] ()
#8  0x0000000104f7368f in -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] ()
#9  0x0000000104f7fe21 in -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] ()
#10 0x0000000104f23457 in -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] ()
#11 0x0000000104f261de in -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] ()
#12 0x0000000104f250d5 in -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] ()
#13 0x0000000107d035e5 in __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 ()
#14 0x00000001045bc41c in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ ()
#15 0x00000001045b2165 in __CFRunLoopDoBlocks ()
#16 0x00000001045b1f25 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#17 0x00000001045b1366 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#18 0x0000000104f24b42 in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#19 0x0000000104f27900 in UIApplicationMain ()
#20 0x000000010449d777 in main at /Users/bjarko/Documents/XCode Projects/SampleProject/SampleProject/AppDelegate.swift:12
#21 0x000000010694b145 in start ()
#22 0x000000010694b145 in start ()
```

Comment: You should add at least the code that is actually crashing. Otherwise it's hard to tell.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. When I run application then debugger break the execution and I see marked line with `firstName` on `SamplePerson` class. Also I see: _Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x7ffe91d2c750)_.

Comment: Since there is so little code, you should be able to reproduce in a playground. Compare: https://gist.github.com/rnapier/99de6094813bf9758f03, which seems to run fine. Look for what you're doing differently, and focus on that first.

Comment: When I put `PersonType` (in mine code is `IPerson`) to file where is `PersonHelper` class - it's run fine. Problem occurs when I put `PersonType` in separate file (`PersonType.swift`) - that's why I thought it's Swift's bug. Comiple without errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At last i found solution! In project settings should set **Whole Module Optimization** on **Yes** (by default is **No**) and it works.
I found article https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=27 about optimization and this provides information:

> "(...) if Whole Module Optimization is enabled, all of the module is compiled
>   together at the same time (...)"

That's why problem not occured when I put all in one file.

Comment: I had a similar problem where the app would get EXC_BAD_ACCESS from swift_getGenericWitnessTable and enabling Whole Module Optimization made it go away.

Answer (score 0):

Without the actual crash stack and code that is involved in the crash, it is difficult to debug, but the symptoms you're describing strongly suggest you're creating undefined behavior. Undefined behavior doesn't mean your program crashes. It means *anything* could happen. It could work. It could overwrite data randomly. It could jump to arbitrary points in the program. It could crash. Undefined is undefined. I would put "bug in Swift language" low on the list of likely reasons. There are many bugs currently in the Swift compiler; but it's still more likely you than it.

You should audit usage of the variable that you are accessing when your program crashes. You should first check for anywhere you are mutating data on a GCD queue other than main. If you're using `dispatch_async` or `NSOperation` (and especially if you're tried to use `NSThread` or any other pure-threading interface, which you shouldn't use), those are the most likely places for mistakes that would look like this.

(I note that you've prefixed protocols with `I...` which is often a Javaism and is not good Swift style. Swift uses `...Type` for this kind of situation, so this should be `PersonType`. It could also be called `Nameable` or `PersonNameable` to focus on the methods it provides. The fact that you've used Javaisms suggests that you may be unfamiliar with GCD, so it is especially suspicious.)

You should carefully inspect any use of `Unsafe...` types (particularly `UnsafeMutablePointer`). These can certainly stomp on memory in tricky ways. You should carefully inspect any use of `!` (and avoid its use). These are less likely to be the problem here given your description, but can certainly cause crashes.

Comment: Thank you for posting. Yes, I'm C# developer, so I named interfaces/protocols with prefix `I...` in Swift I'm new. I created project with default settings added mentioned above classes and protocols and that's all. Since a few days I have no idea what's wrong with this. I updated my question (put stack trace).