# I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x30) Bad Access even when object exists - swift 4

Tags: initialization, swift4, exc-bad-access, xcode9

Similar to [This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45646141/getting-exc-bad-access-while-the-object-exists) and [This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528974/perhaps-the-weirdest-exc-bad-access-ive-seen-swift-generate)

I initialize a variable ----> idHERE:

```
static func createPractitionerRole(fromRoleDict roleDict:[String: AnyObject])->PractitionerRole?{

    guard let (nameL, idL) = getRoleNameId(fromRoleDict:roleDict) else {
            return nil
    }

    let roleTypeL = ProTouchRoleType.determineRoleTypeFromProTouchId(idL)

    var idHERE =  Identifier(withValue: idL, systemParam:Constants.CodeSystem.ProTouch.coding_system_proTouchURL)

    print("idHERE \(String(describing:  idHERE))")

    print("idHERE.value \(String(describing:  idHERE.value))")

    return PractitionerRoleUtils.createPractitionerRole(withId:idHERE, name: nameL, roleType: roleTypeL)
}
```

On the first print it prints out the object:

```
idHERE Identifier Object- system:Optional(http://www.anyApp.com/any) value:Optional("319/43") use:usual period:nil
```

But on the second print when I try to use 
    idHERE.value - I get a bad access EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x30)

How is this possible?

The debugger shows all the values fine as well.

I have tried running the code in release mode with no help.

Please help!!

Xcode 9 swift4

Also, I changed this from a let to a var to see if that made a difference.

This after some complicated code, but I'm not sure why that would make a difference.  Why, if you initialize something, can't you access the values immediately after.

Also, deinit is NOT called.  I have a print statement for deinit and it is not called.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Also I enabled Zombies and did not get anything - FYI

Comment: Also, this same code was working in swift 3

Comment: Also, I have tried calling this from the main thread

Answer (score 0):

My only work around as of now is changing the optimization level to -02 for both release and debug.  Now it "works".  Someone from swift needs to look at this!!

[Links to Look at Later 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999742/generics-and-exc-bad-access-in-swift)

[Also had bad access and changed optimization level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528974/perhaps-the-weirdest-exc-bad-access-ive-seen-swift-generate)